# How to start lxde (lxsession) as a non-root user from ubuntu chroot on android phone?

Tags: permissions, display, android, lxde, chroot

I've built ubuntu-armhf on a partition on a memory card on moto g 4g phone, i can chroot to this and start lxde on an x-server app running on localhost:0 on the phone, this works fine as root, the desktop loads and can install and run programs no problem. I then create a new user on the chroot ubuntu but when i run lxsession as this user i get GTK-warning cannot open display.  I can run "sudo lxsession" as this user but this gives me a desktop on the x-server app with root permission, the same as running lxsession from the root account. Is there a way to start lxde from the user account and get a desktop with only the users permissions? This feels like a permissions problem as everything works fine up to the point when i become a non root user...I've learnt a lot setting this up but this is where i've hit a wall.
Thanks for the help, can provide any aditional info as needed.

Answer (score 1):

I use LXDE in an chrooted Debian loopback with tightvnc on my Nexus 9.

(tightvnc starts a new X-Server. You need a VNC-client app, like [androidVNC](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=vnc&fdid=android.androidVNC), which is FOSS. You don't need a X-Sever-app.)

To start the vnc-server as non-root, you need to be in the inet-group of Android to open sockets.

```
root@chroot$ groupadd -g 3003 android_inet
root@chroot$ useradd NOROOTUSER android_inet
```

Login to your USER and start tightvnc.
Login with your favorite vncclient app to localhost:5901.

BTW, if you want to access the local sdcard, you also need to be in the sdcard_rw (gid=1015) and sdcard_r (gid=1028) group, the procedure is the same.

The gids may differ. To get them, type `id -G` (outside chroot) in a Terminal Emulator.

Be aware, that VNC does not encrypt! If your input is sensitive or you don't trust the network environment, use a ssh tunnel.